# Backend for Angular 2 suggestions?

Tags: angular, web

I would like to know the best/ideal backend/server side programs while using Angular 2 as the front end. Nodes Js, Ruby are the ones I read which are good enough. But can we use Java as well? Is that a good practice? Also please do suggest the in demand technologies for the same.

Comment: django framework

Comment: There is no best/ideal. Backend is completely seperate from frontend. Suggestions: Spring-Boot, .NET Core

Comment: SO is not for suggestions , you decide what is best according to the apps needs

Comment: @RahulSingh , being a starter I was asking suggestions.

Comment: Thank you @Robert

Comment: Just go with what you feel the most comfortable with. Later on you will discover why you would choose one over the others, because each technology has its perks and downsides.

Comment: @Amal i get it but you can get it easily on the web a bit of research will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use NodeJs for the backend, mine being a comparatively small application. If you can provide better insight on the application you want to build on, may be I can try to help.

Answer (score 3):

Angular produces plain html, css and js-files. So you just need a simple webserver like nginx.

If you need a backend for persisting data, it's recommended to create an API. Which technology you should choose for this API mostly depends on your case:
- What database are you using? For MongoDB, NodeJS is obvious.
- Is performance important? golang is really fast.
- Do you want to do things with Microsoft products, like word or excel? C# is a good idea.

And so on... In most cases, just use what you are already experienced with.